# Search java file for line and output to another file with batch script

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to find a specific string in a java file. It'll be matched against the unique string 'private static String currentVersion'. In the file this is a declaration, so I am interested in outputting the entire line to another file.

I currently do this by using the following code:

```
set "xprvar="
for /F "skip=34 delims=" %%i in (ClientGUI.java) do set "xprvar=%%i"&goto nextline
:nextline
echo %xprvar% > clientversion.txt
```

This works, only if the line is always line 35 storing this data. I will make changes to this file so I was wondering if it was possible to have more dynamic approach by matching the string stated above.

Another thing I tried is

```
findstr /s /b "private static String currentVersion" ClientGUI.java
```

However this seems to only match against private or static or String or currentVersion, not the whole string.

Comment: Well you don't need the `/S` option and your search string is actually 4 individual strings, which you'd have noticed had you read the output from `findstr /?`. If would instead use `find.exe`, e.g. `Find /I "private static String currentVersion" < "ClientGUI.java" > "clientversion.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the four words as a single string match with [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) try:

```dos
FindStr /IC:"private static String currentVersion" "ClientGUI.java">"clientversion.txt" 2>NUL
```

You could, if you wish, also just retrieve the 'doublequoted' version string.

```dos
For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %A In ('FindStr /IC:"private static String currentVersion" "ClientGUI.java" 2^>NUL')Do @>"clientversion.txt" Echo(%A
```

---

You can retrieve the line using [find](/questions/tagged/find) too:

```dos
Find /I "private static String currentVersion"<"ClientGUI.java">"clientversion.txt" 2>NUL
```

…and similarly the version string only:

```dos
For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %A In ('Find "private static String currentVersion"^<"ClientGUI.java" 2^>NUL')Do @>"clientversion.txt" Echo(%A
```

---

As I stated in my comment, regarding your use of the `/S` option, you can learn how to use almost any command by using its help option, **`/?`** at the Command Prompt:

- FindStr /?
- Find /?
- For /?